# How to rotate a 3D object around another point in Processing?

Tags: 3d, rotation, processing

Here's a very simple Processing program that rotates a cube around the x-axis. In Processing, the box function's parameters are for the size of the box, but not the location. So in order to move the box I translate it; however, I want to know how to be able to move the box wherever, but rotate around another point. In this case, let's say I want to rotate the box around (0,0,0) instead of the translated point, how should I do that?

```
float rot = 1;
PShape model;
void setup(){
  size(500,500,P3D);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotateX(rot);
  rot+=.005;
  box(40);
  //shape(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked around a little more and found a good resource on the Processing forum answered by the user Chrisir: https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/3d-rotation-logic-problem.html

This program depicts different examples of rotating objects. The last example (of the blue cube) at the bottom depicts how to create an object that rotates around another point:

```
float myAngle=-90; // degree measurement

void setup () {
  // Init
  // 3D requires P3D or OPENGL as a parameter to size()
  size (600, 600, P3D);
}

void draw () {
  // repeated continously
  background(22);
  // switch on lights  
  lights();
  // color for lines
  stroke(111);
  // 
  // Box: A box with equal dimension on all sides is a cube.
  // red: in a distance around Y-axis
  pushMatrix();
  rotateY(radians(myAngle));
  translate(158, 148, -10); 
  fill (color(242, 2, 2));  // red
  box(40); // only one parameter: box(size);
  popMatrix();
  // 
  // Box: A box with equal dimension on all sides is a cube.
  // green: around itself 
  pushMatrix();
  translate(258, 448, -10); 
  rotateY(radians(myAngle));
  fill (color(2, 222, 2)); // green
  box(40); // only one parameter: box(size);
  popMatrix();
  //
  // Box: A box with equal dimension on all sides is a cube.
  // blue: around the green box
  translate(258, 0, 0); 
  pushMatrix();
  rotateY(radians(myAngle));
  translate(158, 448, -10); 
  fill (color(2, 2, 222)); // blue
  box(40); // only one parameter: box(size);
  popMatrix();
  // 
  myAngle+=3; // speed
  if (myAngle>=360) {
    myAngle=0; // keep in degree
  }
  //
}
```